# Model an overview object in an object oriented way

Tags: oop, design-patterns, api-design

I have an api that displays, let's say, cities:

```
/cities
/city/{id}
```

The cities endpoint returns an overview of the city (id, city name, city area), whereas the city endpoint returns the same plus some more (population, image, thumbnail...). Now, when modelling this in the client I see different alternatives:

1. Have a CityOverview class which has a City subclass that adds the extra attributes.
2. Have a City class that has all the attributes with a CityOverview subclass that hides all the extra attributes (say, in Java, by throwing an UnsupportedOperationException on all the getters for attributes it doesn't have).
3. Have the above classes with no inheritance relationship.
4. Have a single City class that allows all the extra attributes to be nulled.

What are the pros and cons of the above approaces and/or any other you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 3 - have 2 classes ,i.e. not an inheritance relationship. Here are the reasons for this decisions -

- You will need to de-serialize\serialize JSON using an api such as jackson. For this you will need a field mapped POJO. Since, you have 2 separate classes now, you can map different POJOs to the 2 different api calls. It makes the code cleaner.
- Inheritance is not an option because of 2 reasons - 1).At one time any of your API calls will either bring data for parent or child. I.e. the fields of either will always be empty depending on which API call you make. This is an unnecessary waste.
- 2). From an OOP design point-of-view the data object being returned in cities call is *not* a parent of the data being returned in the city{id} call. So, we should not have this in the class design as well. They together make up the "City" entity.

Comment: So, I personally went with option 1 for the moment but this is the kind of discussion I was looking for. About your first point, yeah, and I send the parent or child class accordingly. No real problem here. Second point, I don't get it. No fields are empty because I only use the child class on the second endpoint. What do I gain then from option 3?

Comment: I think we are almost on the same page. Only difference being that in point 2 I am saying that CityOverview is "not" a parent of City. In terms of OOPS, City and CityOverview together make up the "City" entity. And then if there is no parent-child relationship but rather an "association" between the 2 classes with CityOverview holding an instance of City - this is point 3 - but since you said that City anyways has all the fields retrieved earlier in CityOverview call then I guess point 3 is not needed. I will edit the solution to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if there is not a big difference between the OverviewCity and the City You should only keep a single City class in the BE.

In your /cities api your can pass the full list of your cities.
Displaying a list of cities with a few details on each city (OverviewCity) can be created easily from a City object by the client side.
In the Backend I dont think there is any need to support 2 classes.

Comment: It's clear to me that the backend doesn't need two classes, it's the client I'm intrigued about. The reason I have less details in the city list is for efficiency as this response could be huge otherwise so I don't want to do the scrapping of extra attributes on the client.